# How to store and retrieve what was selected from a single choice item

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code:

```
protected void showSelectToDialog() {
        boolean[] checkedDate = new boolean[toDate.length];
        int count = toDate.length;

        DialogInterface.OnClickListener setD2 = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onChangeSelectedTo(which);
            }
        };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Select To Year");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(toDate, count, setD2);

        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog2 = builder.create();
        dialog2.show();
    }

    protected void onChangeSelectedTo(int j) {
        bTo.setText(toDate[j]);
        sTo = ((AlertDialog)dialog2).getListView().getCheckedItemPosition();
        blTo = true;
        displayToast(String.valueOf(sTo));
        to = j;
        dialog2.dismiss();
    }
```

What I am looking to do is, when the dialog loads the first time and the user selects a choice it is stored. So the next time the user opens the dialog, it will remember what was select and scroll to that choice.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: use shared Preferences ?

Comment: Possible. But where do I set the selection when it loads up?

Comment: please check if my solution works for you.

Comment: What line do I have to add to set the selection in the single choice?

Comment: I don't understand completely what you mean but I think you mean how to select default value in `setSingleChoiceItems()`. Is it so? If so, then no need to do anything special, 2nd arguement in `setSingleChoiceItems()` is always the default choice. So it will be selected automatically

Comment: I have this line: `builder.setSingleChoiceItems(toDate, count, setD2);` but everytime the dialog loads, nothing is selected.

Comment: Are you updating value of count as I mentioned?

Comment: I changed the line to: `builder.setSingleChoiceItems(toDate, to, setD2);` which was saved the last time a user selected an option but it still not highlighted. Nevermind, it's working now :P No need for SharedPreferences

Comment: Are you restarting the activity? If so then to might not have any value, if not, then check what value to is having every time using Log. This might tell you what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the selected choice's position for the first time using Shared Preferences. 
Then at the start of `showSelectToDialog()` check if any value exists in Shared Preferences, if so, then set the value of `count` from the Shared Preferences else set value of count to `toDate.length`.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see the rest of your code, but all you have to do is save the user's choice in a variable somewhere else, and then read that choice every time you open the dialogue. It could be a static variable on the class, or it could be an instance variable of the class, or it could be a public field of some other class you have access to, like a parent object. You just need to assign it when you close the dialogue, and read it back and initialize the value to what you read when you open the dialogue.

Comment: `to=j` is where I'm saving the value. How do I modify so he next time the dialog loads its selected. That's where I'm having the issue...

Comment: I already told you. In showSelectToDialog() you need to check the value from somewhere else you've saved it, and set bTo.setText(toDate[j]); then in onChangeSelectedTo(...) you need to change the value for the default wherever else you've saved it, so next time it is read it will be different.